# linq: select (d => func(val, d)) siendo d un objeto genérico da error

Tags: c#, sqlite, linq

Tengo el siguiente código:

`List<object>data` es una lista de datos que no tienen por qué ser del mismo tipo, de hecho se espera que sean de distinta clase.

Tengo un método que guarda un objeto en la base de datos:

```
internal void writeData(SQLiteConnection c, object data) 
{
    c.Insert(data);
}
```

Ahora estoy intentando guardar cada elemento de la lista en la base de datos llamando a esta función, algo así como:

```
var v = data.Select(d => writeData(conn, d));
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error

> 'The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Select(IEnumerable, Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo arreglar esto?

A priori, no sé de qué tipo será cada elemento de `data`, hay como 20 clases definidas. Podría comprobar uno a uno de qué tipo es cada elemento, pero eso sería muy tedioso y estoy buscando una manera de hacerlo todo de golpe. No sé si sería posible.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El problema es el var ahi.. cambialo a object y va a funcionar...

Comment: cambiando var v por object v no funciona

Comment: Espera.. pero ese select no deberia devolver nada.. para que haces un select ahi de una funcion que no devuelve nada?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Enumerable.Select`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) espera un valor de retorno pero `writeData` retorna `void`. Deberias de utilizar el metodo extensor [`List<T>.ForEach`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=netframework-4.8) que no espera ningun retorno:

```
data.ToList()
.ForEach(d => writeData(conn, d));
```

Comment: Gracias! al final cambié un poco e hice que writeData devolviera un entero y con eso se arregló

Comment: Excelente. Me alegra que lo hayas solucionado.